# Background color in some /row/entry informaltable

Tags: xpath, xslt, xsl-fo, docbook

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Wr0.jpg)
[XSLT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIbZ6.jpg)

The problem I'm having is that when I export the XML file applying the stylesheets the syntax is correct, but it doesn't apply the background color to the cells of the informaltable.

The output method is  and we are aplying "pdf" format to the final file (xmlns:fo).

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!.

We have tried to apply diferent codes and the result is always to obtain cells in white background color.

```
@MartinHonnen relevant code examples XSLT: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?stylesheet-label Adasa's template for PDF and PostScript creation?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
                version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="docbook5-config:xsl/fo/docbook.xsl"/>
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:attribute-set name="table.table.properties">
      <xsl:attribute name="border-before-width.conditionality">retain</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="border-collapse">collapse</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    
    <xsl:template match="informaltable[@role='blue-table']">
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="blue_table"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="row/entry[1]/para" mode="blue_table">
      <xsl:attribute name="background-color">#0E2F48</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="color">#FF0000</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

Relevant code examples XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section version="5.1" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xmlns:xila="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude/local-attributes"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:trans="http://docbook.org/ns/transclusion"
         xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
         xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
  <title>Equipo de Trabajo</title>
       
  <para>A continuación se describen las funciones y responsabilidades para cada uno de los perfiles que aparecen en la descripción de medios.</para>

  <informaltable role="blue_table">
    <tgroup cols="2">
      <colspec colname="c1" colwidth="310*"/>
      <colspec colname="c2" colwidth="690*"/>

      <tbody>
        <row>
          <entry valign="middle">
            <para>Delegado del Contratista</para>
          </entry>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the relevant code samples as text code samples/snippets. It also seems both your links show XSLT. Are you using your own stylesheets for the whole processing or are you adapting existing docbook stylesheets? It would help to name the exact version.

Comment: Your 'XML' graphic shows the same XSLT as the 'XSLT' graphic. As @MartinHonnen said, your question will be more readable if the XML and XSLT code are included in the question text. The '?' icon in the editor toolbar will give you hints about how to include code blocks. Also, one minimal way to check if your template is being used at all is to add an `xsl:message` in the template and check whether you see the message when you run your transformation.

Comment: I expect that your `row/entry[1]/para` template is never being used. The template generates two attributes but does not process the content of the `para`. If the template is used, you would find that the content of the `para` is missing from your result.

Comment: I have added code relevant examples from XSLT and XML files. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the imported stylesheet set the `xpath-default-namespace` to the DocBook namespace? Otherwise the match pattern like `informaltable[@role='blue-table']` will not work as they match e.g. a template of the name `informaltable` in no namespace. I also don't see how the two templates that would just output two attributes are supposed to make sure those attributes are integrated in the XSL-FO table I suppose the whole stylesheet would map an informaltable to.